# Code running in Chrome Console does not work in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm setting up Facebook Scraper with puppeteer but I have checked this code in Chrome console and it works.

I have listed the class, I need to get the id of the class I have listed.

[Chrome Console query Selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2Qrf.png)

[Puppeteer Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUILN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following?

```
let post_id = await postElement.evaluate(() => {
    return {
        document.querySelector('div[class="_5pcb _4b01 _2q8l"]').id,
    }
})
```

Comment: it's not work

" TypeError: postElement.evaluate is not a function "